# Something wrong with passing parameter to FB Api() method

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I've the following code that fetches my friends list with some specific fields to be returned.

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    fbApp = new FacebookApp();
    authorizer = new CanvasAuthorizer(fbApp);
    authorizer.Perms = requiredAppPermissions;

    if (fbApp.Session != null)
    {
        dynamic friendsFields = new ExpandoObject();
        friendsFields.fields = "id,name,location,bio,gender,religion,activities";
        JsonObject data = fbApp.Get("/me/friends", friendsFields);

        ViewData["friends"] = data["data"] as JsonArray;

        return View();
    }
}
```

I'm asking for id,name,location,bio,gender,religion,activities fields, but the result doesn't submit all those fields. Only id,name,gender are returned which makes suspect something is wrong... if i try to get the same data using the browser and passing the fields the result returns all the requested fields:

```
URL: https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=id,name,bio,gender,picture,religion,activities&access_token=...
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "data_data_data",
         "name": "data_data_data",
         "bio": "data_data_data",
         "gender": "data_data_data",
         "religion": "data_data_data",
         "picture": "data_data_data",
         "activities": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "name": "data_data_data",
                  "category": "data_data_data",
                  "id": "data_data_data",
                  "created_time": "data_data_data"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "id": "data_data_data",
         "name": "data_data_data",
         "bio": "data_data_data",
         "gender": "data_data_data",
         "picture": "data_data_data"
      }
   ]
}
```

Anyone have any idea what might be wrong here? Can it be the API? I'm using the latest version 4.1.1

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the result of the Get method or just access it dynamically. Here is the corrected code with the authorization fixed as well.

```
[CanvasAuthorize(Perms="user_friends")]
public ActionResult Test()
{
    var fbApp = new FacebookApp();  
    dynamic friendsFields = new ExpandoObject();
    friendsFields.fields = "id,name,location,bio,gender,religion,activities";
    dynamic result = fbApp.Get("/me/friends", friendsFields);

    var data = result.data as JsonArray;
    ViewData["friends"] = data;

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Hi Nathan! Isn't your code the same that i have? btw... in the View code how would you do to get the fields? Thanks.